# Angular 8 and C# controllers

Tags: c#, .net-core, angular8

This question has minimal code because I'm struggling to understand the concept, so I don't know where to start. I'm pretty new to Angular. I have projects that are currently in ASP.NET MVC that are probably going to be converted to .NET CORE with an Angular 8 'face'.

I can get Angular to do all sorts of stuff, but I'm struggling to get it to talk to a BLL (or other projects with methods in general). The default Angular 8 project in VS 2019 has a WeatherForecastController, and I can get the controller to talk to the other projects, leading me to believe that the controller talks to the BLL and somehow the .ts file talks to the controller. But this seems very MVC minded (I am primarily an MVC programmer).

So let's say in my BLL I have this method:

```
public class Toolbox
    {
        public User CreateUser()
        {
            User user = new User()
            {
                FirstName = "Jon",
                LastName = "Snow",
                ID = 1234
            };

            return user;
        }
    }
```

Then in my Angular 8 project, I have a controller called UserController, and it does this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    Toolbox toolbox = new Toolbox();

    public User CreatingAUser()
    {
        return toolbox.CreateUser();
    }
}
```

I added the controller manually (i.e. there aren't any references to this controller ANYWHERE else in the project. Not in the app.module.ts file or angular.json file or anywhere else.

What are the next steps to get my view to magically show "Jon Snow 1234"?

Also, if this is entirely the wrong way to do it, please let me know a better way. however, we have hundreds of methods in dozens and dozens of folders, so I don't just want to re-write everything into Angular. I'll need a way to reuse at least most of the code, if possible.

As far as previous research goes, I can find some stuff but its for AngularJS and is outdated or not quite what I'm looking for. I did google it before posting this.

Comment: Does the endpoint work? Are you getting the user returned, and you are not sure how to call this from angular? Or is it something different?

Comment: Right now, nothing is calling the controller's method. I have no idea how to connect the controller to to the .ts file and I can't find any examples online.

Comment: "somehow the .ts file talks to the controller". TypeScript/javaScript running in the browser can communicate with server code using HTTP requests. Either by generating an AJAX request, or causing the page to post back, or causing the browser to navigate to a new page/URL. That's true no matter if the client is Angular or just plain Javascript, or whether the server is C#/MVC, python, Java, PHP or anything else. Those are just the basic facts of web-based applications - they use HTTP.

Comment: As has been eluded to by ADyson, you need to call the endpoint via HTTP. Take a read of this: https://www.djamware.com/post/5d8d7fc10daa6c77eed3b2f2/angular-8-tutorial-rest-api-and-httpclient-examples